# How to resize an UIImageView (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, swift

I'm a beginner with swift and I can't get the resize of a UIImageView working.

Here is my current layout :

[image: Current layout]

What I want is to resize the images to occupy half the screen's width (2 images per row).

Here is my storyboard :

[image: storyboard]

Here is the function drawing the collection view inside my controller :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {
        var cell : MenuInspirationCellView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MenuInspirationCellView

        cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor

        //This is my first approach trying to modify the frame :
        cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.bounds.width / 2,v120)
        var cellImage : UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:              images[indexPath.row]))) 
        cell.imageView.image = cellImage;

        //This is my second approach (based on http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/89236/Resize-Image-in-iOS-Swift) :


        // to resize an image to dimension 52x52
        //var newSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 52,height: 52)
        //let rect = CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height)
        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        // image is a variable of type UIImage
        //cellImage.drawInRect(rect)
        //let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        //UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        // resized image is stored in constant newImage
        //cell.imageView.image = newImage;


        //This is my thrid approach (based on https://gist.github.com/hcatlin/180e81cd961573e3c54d, of course i added his functions but I don't show them here for the sake of readability) :
         //cell.imageView.image = self.RBSquareImageTo(cellImage, size: CGSize(width: 80, height: 80))

        return cell
    }
```

Any leads to sort this out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sizes of your cells are decided by your `UICollectionViewLayout` object, which is a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` in your case. If you want all of your cells to be the same size, you can configure the properties on the layout itself; `itemSize` and `minimumInterimSpacing` will do the trick. Alternatively, if you want your cells to be different sizes, say depending on the image each contains or whatever, you needs your collection view delegate to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method:

```
optional func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGSize
```

returning the size you want for each cell.

Comment: Thanks ! Now I'm able to dynamically resize my cells. But how could I resize the image inside each cell ?

Comment: No problem, @AlexandreNucera. The image inside each cell can be resized by adjusting the various autolayout constraints in your xib or in the code, setting the `UIImageView`'s `autoresizingMask` property, or manually doing the layout in `MenuInspirationCellView`'s `layoutSubviews` function.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. I got this working by modifying my constraints (I removed the fixed 120 width and height).

Answer (score 4):

SWIFT:

```
func imageResize(imageObj:UIImage, sizeChange:CGSize)-> UIImage {

    let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeChange, !hasAlpha, scale)
    imageObj.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: sizeChange))

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext() // !!!
    return scaledImage
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following this tutorials you can resize UIImage, In that tutorial described fully ..  [**Image Resize in swift ios8**](http://www.jogendra.com/2014/11/image-resize-in-swift-ios8.html)

```
    func imageResize (imageObj:UIImage, sizeChange:CGSize)-> UIImage{

     let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeChange, !hasAlpha, scale)
    imageObj.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: sizeChange))

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    return scaledImage
}
```

Here you can also see many tutorials about **Swift language**  Visit Here [**iPhone & iPad Application Development Help World**](http://www.jogendra.com/)